# RoR - Rendering a partial dynamically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm currently trying to load a partial when a button is clicked. So what I do, is add a remote => true, and then a format.js in the controller action that goes to a .js.erb file where I do this:

```
$('#videospan').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'newpartial') %>');
```

Now videospan already had a different partial, and now I'm adding this partial instead. This works fine when it comes to the html part of it. Now newpartial has some javascript inside it, which unfortunately is not detected. Is it because the html was loaded before the javascript?
How can I make it visibile to the HTML? Do I have to define it in the original html file?

Thank you,

---

One of the javascript methods:

```
function saveAll()
{
     for(key in storedData){
        storedData[key].push.apply(storedData[key],[$('#'+key).position().top,$('#'+key).position().left]);
    }


    $.getJSON('<%= save_answers2_course_lecture_path(@course, @lecture) %>',{"stored":storedData}, function(resp){
        redirect()
    });
}
```

---

So now I'm trying to pass the javascript by adding it to the js.erb as well, so now I have this in the js.erb:

```
$('#videospan').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'newpartial') %>');
pop = Popcorn.youtube( "#youtube", lec ,{ width: 400, controls: 0});                           
pop.play();
```

So I want to render the partial which has a #youtube div inside which I then want to use popcorn to add a video to it. Unfortunately, when I add these 3 lines, even the rendering doesn't work..

---

With firebug, when I check the Response returned, it looks like this:

```
$('#videospan').html(".........");
pop = Popcorn.youtube( "#youtube", http://www.youtube.com/... ,{ width: 400, controls: 0}); 
pop.controls( false );                          
pop.play();
```

So everything is sent correctly, but how come it's not displayed?

Comment: What do you mean the javascript in newpartial is not detected?

Comment: jQuery wont detect that there is javascript code inside the string you pass to `#html()`

Comment: @JohnNaegle I mean I have some javascript methods in that partial. When I call them, they're not found.

Comment: @KaiKönig oh ok, well is there another way to pass the partial as well as it's javascript code?

Comment: post the javascript that is defined in newpartial

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone faces the someone problem.. It was due to an error I had. According to this: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/

The code fails in silence when there are errors in the .js.erb file. To check for errors simply copy the response from firebug, post it in the command line and run it.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off moving as much Javascript as possible into script files. One approach is to break up the functionality into code vs. configuration data: put the code in a .js file, and the data into the DOM or a variable:

```
// Option1 -- Using DOM
// my_function.js
function saveAll() {
  // code code code
  var url = $('#some_dom_element').attr('data-some-attribute-name');

  $.getJSON(url, 'blah blah');
}

# my_template.js.erb
<div id="some_dom_element" data-some-attribute-name="<%= save_answers2_course_lecture_path( @course, @lecture) %>">
</div>

// Option 2 -- Using a variable
// my_function.js
function saveAll() {
  // code code code
  $.getJSON(url, 'blah blah');
}

# my_template.js.erb
var url = '<%= raw(save_answers2_course_lecture_path( @course, @lecture) %>';
```

Comment: Ok, well say now I'm rendering the partial like above, and I want to access that javascript code from there. I tried the method you suggessted using the .js.erb, but I think the problem is in the .js file.. To be more precise I have an onload method that needs to be called when this partial is rendered.. how can I do that?

Comment: If you're rendering javascript, whatever is in the `.js.erb` will run on the page when the response returns. So you can just put the javascript in the template directly and avoid the `onload`.

Comment: Oh ok.. I tried that.. but I'm not sure why it's not working. I added the code to the question

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you added. Are you sure that the target element is being added? Maybe try Firebug and run the JS in the console?

Comment: Yes I checked with firebug.. without the last 2 lines, the partial is rendered.. but when I add them.. it's not.. but for the video to work I need those 2 lines..

Comment: Ok I finally found out what was wrong! Apparently there WAS an error! , a missing " but for some reason the errors don't come up on firebug, you need to copy that response, and paste it in firebug's command line, and only then will the errors appear! I found that here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/